# chart.js control space between/size of gridlines

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a line chart in chart.js that plots data from financial markets.

How can I control the width of the gridlines from the x axis?

The data is time based and when the chart starts the space between the gridlines is too big. 
[image: Too Big]

As the data is added the chart condenses the space automatically.
[image: Getting Smaller]

I would like to control the spacing to a uniform amount that I can set from the start.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: add your code also

Comment: How would the code help? It's a 2000 line script.

Comment: I haven't yet needed to adjust the `gridLines` except for hiding the horizontal ones.  With that said I found this (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration) within the docs, try play around with the `borderDash` property - I think this will help.

Comment: Thanks @Koshux, will try that next

Comment: @kmm2908 Hey did you solve this, if so how? I am also having the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can set a maximum number of vertical grid lines (for x axis) :

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            maxTicksLimit: 20,
        },
    }]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution but by setting a fix hight or width you can control the max-space between the gridLines

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="1200px"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a few days trying to solve this exact problem. This video led me to the ultimate solution to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUAP3szj_u8